# Select values from dictionary based on input

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a couple of `SortedDictionaries`. I don't really know how to fetch a specific value from it by user input.

Here i'm adding information to the dictionary:

```
public SortedDictionary<int, List<double>> addqtyScrews() 
{
            qtyScrews.Add(5, new List<double>()); // key 5
            qtyScrews[5].Add(0);
            qtyScrews[5].Add(0.5);
            qtyScrews[5].Add(1);
            qtyScrews[5].Add(1.5);
            qtyScrews[5].Add(4.5);
            qtyScrews[5].Add(5);
            qtyScrews.Add(6, new List<double>()); // key 6
            qtyScrews[6].Add(0);
            qtyScrews[6].Add(0.5);
            qtyScrews[6].Add(1);
            qtyScrews[6].Add(1.5);
            qtyScrews[6].Add(2);
            qtyScrews[6].Add(2.5);
            qtyScrews[6].Add(3);
}
```

function of what i want, the user inputs their desired key and value values:

```
public void Screws()
{
   int kID = 5; // Key ID
   double vID = 4.5; // Value ID
   var SelectionScrews = qtyScrews.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == kID and y => y.Value == vID).Key; 
} // not correct code, but its what i want it to do pretty much.
```

how do i make the "and" term work here?

Comment: `&& x.Value.Contains(vID)`

Comment: `qtyScrews.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key == kID && kvp.Value.Any(v => v == vID)).Key`

Comment: i don't understand your code.  If you want to have a key, you don't need to query List, kID is your Key. Assume, you are looking not for a key. Why don't you use your dictionary ? why not to write qtyScrews[kID].FirstOrDefault(y=>y.Value == vID) ?

Comment: @MaksimSimkin I cannot use the code you wrote because it sais "double does not contain a definition for Value"

Comment: @Joel yes, sorry it is qtyScrews[kID].FirstOrDefault(y=>y== vID)  but i don't see any sence there, eitehr you need key and it is kID or you need Value and it is vID , you don't need any query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

```
var SelectionScrews = addqtyScrews().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == kID && x.Value.Contains(vID)).Key;
```

however, I suspect what you're looking for is:

```
var SelectionScrews = addqtyScrews().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == kID && x.Value.Contains(vID)).Value;
```

note that `.Value` instead of `.Key`, the latter will return 5, the former the list of values.

In addition, I'd suggest using the following more compact notation for object initialization:

```
qtyScrews.Add(5, new List<double>() { 0, 0.5, ...., 5 });
qtyScrews.Add(6, new List<double>() { 0, 0.5, ...., 3 });
```

so that with 2 lines you replace 10 lines.